# using deque with C library

Tags: c++, c, stl, vector, deque

Lets say I have a structure

```
struct s
{
     std::deque<Object> q; //won't work  with C library
}
```

If the structure with std::deque is initialized using C library then it wouldn't work.

```
struct s
{
     std::vector<Object> v; //would work with C library
}
```

However, this structure with std::vector would work with C library. 
I think this is because the elements in deque are not contiguous whereas the elements in vector are contiguous. I think this might be a reason but not sure.

Comment: Your question is far too vague... What do you mean by "work with a C library?". Also, the prefix is std::, not stl::.

Comment: plz edit your post... and be specific on what u want and what u r trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither version of `S` will work with a C library.
This is because C does not have any concept of how classes are layed out (or even what is in them).

Vector can be used with C library if you pass the address of an element. Because all the elements are in contiguous memory it looks like a normal pointer and thus any C function that takes a pointer will work.

```
struct Object { /* NORAML POD Object */ };

extern "C" void cFunctionCall(Object* data, size_t size);


std::vector<Object>   v;
// initialize v

cFunctionCall(&v[0], v.size()); // This will work because all members of v
                                // are in contiguous memory
```

Comment: +1. One more thing worth pointing out: The vector version of S may "work with a C library" for certain uses, on some particular platform, just because the layout of vector<Object> happens to start with, e.g., "Object \*begin". However, unlike contiguous storage of the contents, that's obviously not guaranteed, it's just a coincidence, so when he upgrades to the next version of his compiler, he may be trying to access "size_t len" as an Object*, and if he's lucky it'll instantly crash.

Comment: @abarnert: Actually contiguous storage of elements in vector is guaranteed by the standard. For exactly this use case. **BUT** the version of S with vector will **never** work as it contains pointers internally not a set of objects.

Comment: Reread my comment. I said that unlike contiguous storage of the contents (which is guaranteed) any particular layout of the vector object itself is not guaranteed.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "it contains pointers internally not a set of objects". What it contains is a vector<Object>, inline. What that looks like depends on the implementation. In many cases, it will be an Object pointer (to the start of the vector), followed by additional pointers and/or sizes (to the end of storage and capacity). If you write C code that treats a single vector<Object> it as an Object pointer, it will work (on those implementations, and then fail badly on different implementations).